# My .rpm package needs to restart the system. So, how can I define it in the .spec file?

Tags: linux, packaging, rpm, reboot

I'm creating a .rpm package for my project.

The .spec file changes some network configurations.
So, I need to reboot the system when the package will be installed/upgraded.

Can I set these kind of action in it as the upgrade kernel packages does?

Thanks!

Comment: That seems really cruel.  Why does it need to restart the computer?

Comment: Why do you need to reboot? Can you not use `/etc/init.d/network restart`?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity The network configurations must be changed only when the user restart the machine. The "The system needs to be restart" icon must appear. Kernel upgrades does it, doesn't it?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I cannot use `/etc/init.d/network restart` for this case. =S

Comment: You probably can `restart/reboot` using `%post` script. But is this good? Probably not. It can cause lost of unsaved data if the user isn't expecting a reboot.

Comment: @alvits For more details, my package needs to do it... http://goo.gl/QqxX3m

Comment: @jcfaracco - It's desktop notification. You need to consult desktop notification API. From your `%post` script, you should issue an API call to set the desktop notification. I'm no expert in desktop notification. I'd suggest opening a question on how to send desktop notifications. Maybe this will be a good start https://developer.gnome.org/libnotify/unstable/libnotify-notify.html and this http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/how-to-use-standard-gnome-notification.html

Answer (score 0):

Dumb idea.

You're not telling us everything, especially *why* you need to reboot the system instead of merely bouncing the network service or the NIC.

Comment: When you upgrade the version of your kernel, for example, an icon appears on systray telling that reboot is required. I need that only for HCI (Human-Computer Interaction). Not because my package really needs.

Answer (score 0):

As of today, there is a `needs-restarting` plugin in RPM: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/27943

> Beginning in RHEL 7, `yum-utils` includes the `needs-restarting` plug-in with support for the `-r`, `--reboothint` flag. This command will report whether a reboot will be needed.

> `# needs-restarting -r`

as well as recommendations to only restart specific services when it's applicable.